# how to install autocomplete in emacs 24.4

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, emacs24

I have no idea how to install autocomplete in emacs24.4, I follow the auto-complete (http://auto-complete.org/) office document,install by load file "install.el", it just fail "Cannot open load file: no such file or directory,popup", by the way ,I download the auto-complete from github. how can I get any information for the auto-complete mode????

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install auto-complete in emacs-24.4 is using the `package` module already integrated in emacs that allows to install packages.

```lisp
(setq package-archives '(("ELPA" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
                         ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
```

- Copy and paste the above lines in your emacs startup file (.emacs or init.el)
- Save and restart emacs.
- Call the following command by typing `M-x: list-packages`
- Search (C-s) for auto-complete
- Press enter on auto-complete package and install it by pressing again on the install button
- Restart emacs. You can enable auto-complete by typing `M-x: auto-c-omplete-mode`

If you do not want to install by hand the package, add the following lines in your emacs startup file:

```lisp
(if (package-installed-p 'auto-complete)
    nil
  (package-install 'auto-complete))
```

Now you can continue configuring auto-complete by requiring it. You do not need to put auto-complete any more in your `load-path`.